# Calling ros::spinOnce() in nodelets?

Tags: ros, spin, threads, callbacks, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to integrate a `while(true){ros::spinOnce(); ..}` loop into a nodelet? I've based mine on the [velodyne_driver](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros-pkg/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Fstacks%2Fcamera1394%2Ftags%2Fcamera1394-1.8.0%2Fsrc%2Fnodes%2F) nodelet, which runs a separate thread which polls the device object.

That while loop never sleeps though, and as the camera driver is a publisher, it doesn't have any callbacks to process, so there is no `ros::spinOnce()` either. I was wondering if that could be added there (to be able to handle callbacks) or if that would clash with the nodelet's manager?

---

<s>EDIT: I know the manager handles the spin logic, it actually calls `spinOnce()` after a 1e6 us usleep (which is equal to what `ros::spin()` does). What I'm really after is a way to reduce that sleep time. I'm guessing that is not possible without changing and recompiling the nodelet manager, but hoping I'm wrong.</s>

EDIT2: ^ all wrong. See @Lorenz's answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37901/calling-ros::spinonce()-in-nodelets?/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nodelet manager doesn't call `spinOnce` but `spin` as you can see in `nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp`, line 296, at least in Fuerte. Spin doesn't do any sleeps but calls `callAvailable` on the global callback queue in a loop. `callAvailable` doesn't sleep on a timeout either. It blocks on a condition variable until a message is received on the queue and executes all callbacks. That means that you shouldn't need to do any special handling or call `spin` or `spinOnce` by hand. Message callbacks should be executed at once, i.e. as soon as the main thread gets computation time by the OS scheduler.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-04**:
yep, you're right. I was looking under the `command == "load"` case, which is different from the manager. `CallbackQueue::callAvailable()` waits on timeout *or* a new event, so no sleeping. Basically, there is no explicit *sleeping*, only *wait on timeout or event* in the whole event loop (AFAICT).

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-04**:
Exactly. However, the timout is only there to stop if ros::ok becomes false, i.e. the manager is shut down.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-04**:
And just to be absolutely clear: the 'no sleeping' also means that -- by default -- ROS tries to handle callbacks 'as fast as possible', to the abilities of the machine on which it runs.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-04**:
Yes. I think so.